# Manage Game Level with enum

Tags: swift, ios, enum

Basically What I have is basket ball App. In which I have Added some levels and difficulties. logic is simply use tupple in enum and I have some methods to update / get current level with new values

I have created following code

```
enum Difficulty:String {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
    func getRatioForTargetAgaintsAvailable() -> Float {
        switch  self {
        case .easy:
            return 0.3
        case .medium:
            return 0.5
        case .hard :
            return 0.8
        }
    }

    func getDistanceForTarget () -> Float {
        switch  self {
        case .easy:
            return 5
        case .medium:
            return 6
        case .hard :
            return 7
        }
    }

}
```

And main enum

```
enum Level:CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "Welcome to New  \(self.getDifficulty().rawValue) Level , Your Target is \(getTargetValue()), You have \(getAvailableBalls()) Balls left"
    }

    case level1(avaiableBalls:Int,difficulty:Difficulty,totalScore:Int)
    case level2(avaiableBalls:Int,difficulty:Difficulty,totalScore:Int)
    case level3(avaiableBalls:Int,difficulty:Difficulty,totalScore:Int)

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //MARK:- Set  Methdos

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    mutating func updateTotalScore (newValue:Int) {
        switch self {

        case .level1(  let availableBall, let  difficulty,  _):
            self = Level.level1(avaiableBalls: availableBall, difficulty: difficulty, totalScore: newValue)

        case .level2(   let availableBall, let  difficulty,   _):
            self = Level.level2(avaiableBalls: availableBall, difficulty: difficulty, totalScore: newValue)


        case .level3(   let availableBall, let  difficulty,   _):
            self = Level.level3(avaiableBalls: availableBall, difficulty: difficulty, totalScore: newValue)

        }
    }

    mutating func updateAvailableBalls (newValue:Int) {
        switch self {

        case .level1( _, let  difficulty,  let totalScore):
            self = Level.level1(avaiableBalls: newValue, difficulty: difficulty, totalScore: totalScore)

        case .level2(   _ , let  difficulty,   let totalScore):
            self = Level.level2(avaiableBalls: newValue, difficulty: difficulty, totalScore: totalScore)


        case .level3(  _ , let  difficulty,   let totalScore):
            self = Level.level3(avaiableBalls: newValue, difficulty: difficulty, totalScore: totalScore)

        }
    }

    mutating func gotoNextLevel() -> Bool {
        switch  self {
        case .level1:
            self = Level.level2(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .medium, totalScore: 0)
            return true
        case .level2:
            self = Level.level2(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .hard, totalScore: 0)
            return true
        case .level3 :
            self = Level.level3(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .hard, totalScore: 0)
            return false


        }
    }

    mutating func restartLevel () {
        switch  self {
        case .level1:
            self = Level.level1(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .easy, totalScore: 0)
        case .level2:
            self = Level.level2(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .medium, totalScore: 0)
        case .level3 :
            self = Level.level3(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .hard, totalScore: 0)

        }
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //MARK:-   Get  Methdos

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    func getTotalScore () -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .level1(_,_, let totalScore) :
            return totalScore
        case .level2(_,_, let totalScore) :
            return totalScore

        case .level3(_,_ ,let totalScore):
            return totalScore
        }
    }

    func getAvailableBalls () -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .level1(let availableBall,_,_) :
            return availableBall
        case .level2(let availableBall,_,_) :
            return availableBall

        case .level3(let availableBall,_,_) :
            return availableBall
        }
    }

    func getTargetValue () -> Int {
        switch self{
        case .level1(  let _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return  Int(difficulty.getRatioForTargetAgaintsAvailable() * Float(20))

        case .level2(   let _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return  Int(difficulty.getRatioForTargetAgaintsAvailable() * Float(20))


        case .level3(   let _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return  Int(difficulty.getRatioForTargetAgaintsAvailable() * Float(20))

        }
    }

    func getMinDistanceFromHook () -> Float {
        switch self{
        case .level1(  _, let  difficulty,   _):
                return difficulty.getDistanceForTarget()

        case .level2(   _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return difficulty.getDistanceForTarget()


        case .level3(   _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return difficulty.getDistanceForTarget()
        }
    }

    func getDifficulty () -> Difficulty {
        switch self{
        case .level1(  _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return difficulty

        case .level2(   _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return difficulty

        case .level3(   _, let  difficulty,   _):
            return difficulty
        }
    }

    func isLevelPassed () -> Bool {
        return getTotalScore() == getTargetValue()
    }


}
```

Now In my `ViewController` I create Object

```
var currentLevel = Level.level1(avaiableBalls: 20, difficulty: .easy, totalScore: 0)
```

So my Question is is it good way to implement this functionality  any suggested improvement in it?

Thanks for reading this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Remarks and simplifications for your current code

Swift does not use the “get” prefix for getter methods, so

```
func getDistanceForTarget() -> Float
```

is better named

```
func targetDistance() -> Float
```

Functions which take no argument, have no side-effects, and are idempotent (i.e.
return the same value on each invocation) are often better expressed as a
*read-only computed property,* in your case

```
var targetDistance: Float
```

See [Swift functions vs computed properties](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304077/swift-functions-vs-computed-properties)
on  Software Engineering for a detailed discussion.

The above applies to all of your `getXXX` methods.

---

The `getTotalScore()` function can be simplified to

```
func getTotalScore() -> Int {
    switch self {
    case .level1(_, _, let totalScore),
         .level2(_, _, let totalScore),
         .level3(_, _, let totalScore):
        return totalScore
    }
}
```

since all cases bind the same variable. The same applies to the following
getter methods.

---

The `let` preceding the wildcard pattern in

```
    case .level1(  let _, let  difficulty,   _):
```

is not needed, and causes a compiler warning.

---

The explicit conversion to `Float` in

```
return  Int(difficulty.getRatioForTargetAgaintsAvailable() * Float(20))
```

is not needed since `20` can be both an integer and a floating point literal:

```
return  Int(difficulty.getRatioForTargetAgaintsAvailable() * 20)
```

---

The [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/1539130-description) method of the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol
should provide

> A textual representation of this instance.

You are abusing it for a welcome message.

#### Suggesting an different data structure

Apparently there is a lot of repetition in your code. Adding another level
would require that 9 functions are updated.

If I understand it correctly (I am not a basketball expert!), the `Level`
type is used to store

- A *level* (1, 2, 3). Each level is bound to a `Difficulty` (1 = easy, 
  2 = medium, 3 = hard).
- An integer *available balls.*
- An integer *total score.*

If we make `Difficulty` an `Int`-based enumeration then we can use it directly
as the “level” instead of maintaining that correspondence at several places:

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case easy = 1
    case medium
    case hard
}
```

`Level` now becomes a `struct` with three (independent) properties.
This makes many of the getter methods obsolete:

```
struct PlayerStatus {

    var level: Difficulty
    var availableBalls: Int
    var totalScore: Int
}
```

(I'm using a different name here to avoid confusion with the `level` property.)

With an init method

```
init(level: Difficulty = .easy) {
    self.level = level
    availableBalls = 20
    totalScore = 0
}
```

the creation of an initial status becomes as easy as

```
var currentStatus = PlayerStatus()
```

Because of the integer-based `enum Difficulty`, updating to the next level
can be implemented using the `rawValue` – without a switch/case and independent
of the number of levels:

```
mutating func gotoNextLevel() {
    if let newLevel = Difficulty(rawValue: self.level.rawValue + 1) {
        self = PlayerStatus(level: newLevel)
    } else {
        // Already at the highest level.
    }
}
```

---

Putting it all together, we have

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case easy = 1
    case medium
    case hard

    var targetRatio: Float {
        switch  self {
        case .easy:
            return 0.3
        case .medium:
            return 0.5
        case .hard:
            return 0.8
        }
    }

    var targetDistance: Float {
        switch  self {
        case .easy:
            return 5
        case .medium:
            return 6
        case .hard:
            return 7
        }
    }
}

struct PlayerStatus {

    var level: Difficulty
    var availableBalls: Int
    var totalScore: Int

    init(level: Difficulty = .easy) {
        self.level = level
        availableBalls = 20
        totalScore = 0
    }

    mutating func restartLevel() {
        self = PlayerStatus(level: self.level)
    }

    mutating func gotoNextLevel() {
        if let newLevel = Difficulty(rawValue: self.level.rawValue + 1) {
            self = PlayerStatus(level: newLevel)
        } else {
            // Already at the highest level.
        }
    }

    var targetValue: Int {
        return Int(level.targetRatio * 20)
    }

    var levelPassed: Bool {
        return totalScore == targetValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)  I really appreciate it (You are awesome :-]) Looking forward to get more tips from you

Comment: @Martin R Don’t you think that having “get” prefix is much more clearer in the intent and easy to understand, in general?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh: You'll find the “get” prefix nowhere in the Swift standard library. Such a convention already existed in Objective-C/Cocoa, compare https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html.